# Automatic id generation and mapping _id NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want the id to be automatically generated when I index a document into elastic search. This works fine when I don't specify an Id property in my poco.

What I would like to do is map the underlying _id field onto my poco class when getting and use auto generated id when indexing. It looks like I can either specify the id or not at all. Are their any nest api options that I am missing?

EDIT

Example gist
https://gist.github.com/antonydenyer/9074159

Comment: If you make your http request with POST instead of PUT, elasticsearch will create id automatically.

Answer (score 2):

As @Duc.Duong said in comments you can access Id using `DocumentWithMeta`.
In current version of NEST `DocumentsWithMetaData` is replaced with `Hits` and also you should cast `IHit<DataForGet>.Id` from `string` to `int`.

this is my code:

```cs
public class DataForIndex
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // some other fields...
}

public class DataForGet : DataForIndex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var result = client.Search<DataForGet>(x => x.Index("index").MatchAll());
var list = results.Hits.Select(h =>
                                   {
                                       h.Source.Id = Convert.ToInt32(h.Id);
                                       return h.Source;
                                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

[Automatic ID Generation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#_automatic_id_generation)

> The index operation can be executed without specifying the id. In such a case, an id will be generated automatically. In addition, the op_type will automatically be set to create. Here is an example (note the POST used instead of PUT):

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/' -d '{
  "user" : "kimchy",
  "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
  "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}'
```

Result:

```
{
  "_index" : "twitter",
  "_type" : "tweet",
  "_id" : "6a8ca01c-7896-48e9-81cc-9f70661fcb32",
  "_version" : 1,
  "created" : true
}
```

Comment: Yes, note the POST used instead of PUT

Answer (score -1):

Seem that NEST auto detect "Id" field in class and map it to "_id" in ES. Your requirement look strange but why not create 2 classes for it ? One for indexing (without Id field), one for getting (inherited from indexing class and declare new field "Id") ?

e.g.:

```cs
public class DataForIndex
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // some other fields...
}

public class DataForGet : DataForIndex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this doesn't work. At the moment I'm just enriching the class with the responses by other means. It's not very elegant and just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: @antonydenyer can you update your question with why Duc.Duong suggested answer does not work? This is the best way to tackle this problem but you have to also factor in that nest tries to guess the index and type names for the classes you use. You can fix them by specifying how classes map to index/typenames on ConnectionSettings.

Comment: @MartijnLaarman I'll try and spend some time to put an example together of what I mean and post the gist here when I do. Duc-duong suggestion makes sense but unfortunately it didn't work for me out of the box for me. I seem to remember at the decorating the class and specifying the type but I can't be sure. It could just be that.

Comment: Apologies to all for how long this has taken. This is what I'm talking about https://gist.github.com/antonydenyer/9074159

Comment: yes I see, seem there's a bug in NEST, Id field cannot be serialized correctly in inherited class, you can report a bug on github NEST project. For now you can use DocumentWithMeta to get the Id: `var item = client.Search<DataForGet>(x => x.Index("index").MatchAll());
var list = item.DocumentsWithMetaData.Select(x => { x.Source.Id = x.Id; return x.Source; }).ToList();`

Comment: Are there any plans to fix this behaviour? I too am trying to deserialise objects from Elasticsearch and map the _id value onto my class. Using Duc.Duoung's solution above does work but seems rather inelegant - can't we just specify a `[JsonProperty]` mapping on the class and NEST pulls the _id value through?